# Compare 2 consecutive rows in same table and update row2 with row1 value

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to compare 2 consecutive rows in the same table. If the data is missing in the second row, I should update it with the first row's data.

For Eg:

```
Row   EmpID  DATE        PosID        EmpStatus  EmpDept  EmpVP
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     21     2010-12-31  NULL         TC         NULL     40
2     21     2010-01-25  90156840101  NULL       407      NULL
3     21     2003-11-25  NULL         AC         NULL     NULL
```

First Iteration: Since Row1 EmpStatus = TC, I want to Update the EmpStatus on Row2 to TC (Since its NULL) and EmpVP to 40 on Row2, as shown below:

```
Row   EmpID  DATE        PosID        EmpStatus  EmpDept  EmpVP
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     21     2010-12-31  NULL         TC          NULL    40
2     21     2010-01-25  90156840101  TC          407     40 
3     21     2003-11-25  NULL         AC          NULL    NULL
```

Second Iteration: Since PositionID is NULL on Row3, I want to update Row3 with the PositionID of Row2. Since Row2 now has EmpStatus = TC, I want to compare the row2 and row3 data. Since Row3 has a new value, I want to retain the new value "AC". But at the same time I want to update the value of EmpDept of Row3 = 40 since it's NULL. The desired results are shown below:

```
Row   EmpID  DATE        PosID        EmpStatus  EmpDept  EmpVP
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     21     2010-12-31  NULL         TC          NULL    40
2     21     2010-01-25  90156840101  TC          407     40 
3     21     2003-11-25  90156840101  AC          407     40
```

I am working on historical data load and I have to build records going backwards in terms of Dates.

Can anyone please tell me how to code this?
I want to know if we can do these updates, preferably without using cursors, as I have a lot of employees in this table.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an iterative process which depends not only on each row visited, but also on data changes made during the processing. I can't even begin to imagine how you'd do it without cursors.

I think once you resolve yourself to using cursors, then it's just a matter of determining the rules (in a more general fashion than you've presented them) and then implementing those rules using cursors.

This appears to be a one-time process, so I'm not sure I understand why you'd be concerned about writing a routine that uses cursors to process the data, and running it during a maintenance period or just during a slow-usage period.

Here's some pseudocode for how you might approach this problem (you'll need to get the actual syntax details from a manual and you'll need to make sure your business rules are being applied in the right order and the right manner):

BEGIN

```
DECLARE @row NUMBER, @posID VARCHAR(20), @empStatus VARCHAR(2), @empDept NUMBER, @empVP NUMBER;
DECLARE @prevPosID VARCHAR(20), @prevEmpStatus VARCHAR(2), @prevEmpDept NUMBER, @prevEmpVP NUMBER;
DECLARE @isFirst NUMBER;
SET @isFirst = 1;

DECLARE  mycurs CURSOR FOR
SELECT   Row, PosID, EmpStatus, EmpDept
FROM     Empl
ORDER BY Date DESC
FOR UPDATE OF Empl;

OPEN mycurs;

FETCH NEXT mycurs INTO @row, @posID, @empStatus, @empDept, @empVP;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS != NOTFOUND)
BEGIN
    IF (@isFirst == 1) THEN
    BEGIN
        @isFirst = 0;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@empStatus IS NULL AND @prevEmpStatus IS NOT NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
            SET @empStatus = @prevEmpStatus;
            UPDATE Empl SET EmpStatus = @empStatus WHERE Row = @row;
        END
        IF (@posID IS NULL AND @prevPosID IS NOT NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
            SET @posID = @prevPosID ;
            UPDATE Empl SET PosID = @posID WHERE Row = @row;
        END
        IF (@empDept IS NULL AND @prevEmpDept  IS NOT NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
            SET @empDept = @prevEmpDept;
            UPDATE Empl SET EmpDept= @empDept WHERE Row = @row;
        END
    END

    SET @prevPosID = @posID;
    SET @prevEmpStatus = @empStatus;
    SET @prevEmpDept = @empDept;
    SET @prevEmpVP = @empVP;

    FETCH NEXT mycurs INTO @row, @posID, @empStatus, @empDept, @empVP;
END

DEALLOCATE mycurs;
CLOSE mycurs;
```

END

Comment: I have been asked to refrain from using cursors since I am amateur developer. Is it possible to do this process using a cursor ? Can you please tell me how ?

Comment: If there is concern that you are not enough of a "professional developer" to write this code, then I don't understand why you were assigned to do it -- it's not too difficult, but it is non-trivial. By "amateur developer" do you mean you don't get paid?

Comment: Hmmm. I have about 2 yrs of Access development experience and I have been asked to do this quick hit. I get paid for my regular job.

Comment: A cursor is used to iterate over every row matching a query (could be a simple query with no WHERE clause which retrieves all rows). As you select rows of the cursor, you typically populate variables with the data values you are selecting. Then you can perform logic on those values, and/or save the current values to compare to on the next select. I'll add some pseudo code to my answer to give you an idea.

Comment: I was looking at cursors and it looks pretty easy. But I could not find examples where we can fetch the current and the next row in one instance.

Comment: You can see in my example that what I've done is to save the contents of a row in variables, then move on to the next row. If you find this helpful, please check the check mark next to the answer and also click on the up arrow to vote it up -- this is standard stack overflow protocol for helpful answers.